# How to iterate A list coming from C# Model on relevant View using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to access C# List in my view but in Javascript code as i am using Jquery plugin and this list is basically a dataset for that.

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =new JavaScriptSerializer();
        vModel.JSONResultVMToDoList = jSearializer.Serialize(vModel.VModelToDoList);
this is what returning from model to my view
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you are going about it the wrong way. You need to pass the original vModel.VModelToDoList to your strongly-typed view and then iterate it using C# (Razor), to add rows to a table or whatever. Forget serializing it as JSON. Your code seems to be passing the data to the view twice - once as a .NET data structure and then again as JSON.

The code in the cshtml would be something like

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property1)</td>        
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property2)</td>                 
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property3)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Any object passed from the controller to a view as the model only exists on the server, it never gets to the client browser to be available for use by client-side JavaScript.

(Incidentally, a completely different approach would be to write a WebAPI returning JSON and then call this from JavaScript on the browser. This might be better if you want to provide fast and frequent updates, but if the data is fairly static for a time just create it client-side as mentioned above.)

Comment: thanks for reply..
but my situation is different lets suppose in VModelToDoList there are 3 objects containing 4 properties each.
And want to alert values of all properties on $(document).ready() how can it be possible.?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for the delay in responding!)

I am not sure that is the best way of presenting data to your users but if you have to do this, stick the JSON in a hidden field in the view with a suitable ID. Then in the document ready handler, retrieve the string, parse it to an array, iterate the array and show alerts.